# pam_env(crond:setcred): non-alphanumeric key 'JAVA_HOME =$PATH:

Tags: linux, rhel, security

RHEL - I have many lines in my `/var/log/secure-____` file that are similar to the following:

```
Oct  4 03:05:01 localhost crond[2161]: pam_env(crond:setcred): non-alphanumeric key 'JAVA_HOME =$PATH:/usr/java/jre1.8.0_51' in /etc/environment', ignoring
```

What do these entries mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing it being the space in `JAVA_HOME =....` as the usual form for such assignments is `JAVA_HOME=...`. Try removing that space from the line that should be in `/etc/environment`?

Comment: I have made the change - I will let you know if this resolves the log issue.  Thanks!